# GUID as uniq key with SQLite

Tags: database, sqlite, guid

I found [GUID generation routine with python](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/163604/).

Running the code gives me the following results.

```
GUID: 00000129e0e72d9b2aab3c1500ac001000e90001
    Time:    Sat, 17 Jul 2010 09:55:33 (millis: 0.787)
    IP:      172.16.233.1
    Counter: 715865109
```

The comments of this code has the following message.

```
###   GUIDs make wonderful database keys.  They require no access to the 
###   database (to get the max index number), they are extremely unique, and they sort 
###   automatically by time.   GUIDs prevent key clashes when merging
###   two databases together, combining data, or generating keys in distributed
###   systems.
```

#### Questions

- Does this work with SQLite? As far as I know INTEGER type in SQLite is 8 byte, and with 8 byte, it's not possible to store value 0x00000129e0e72d9b2aab3c1500ac001000e90001 or 101362835865894089778560972572099193929729 in decimal.
- Is there any way to get unique ID globally with SQLite?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Other than the fact that it takes up 32 bytes instead of 16, what's wrong with storing a GUID as text in SQLite?

Comment: Not much. BTW, Can SQLite store INTEGER with 16/32 bit?

Comment: In SQLite3, they do support 64-bit integers.  See here http://www.sqlite.org/version3.html and http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/int64.html.  I believe you define the column as a 'long' or 'unsigned long'.

Answer (score 8):

Good article to help you get decision....

**Primary Keys: IDs vs GUIDs:**

http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/03/primary-keys-ids-versus-guids.html

Answer (score -2):

Every SQLite data row has a 64 bit locally-unique identifier. SELECT rowid FROM table...