# Proper way to store GUID in sqlite

Tags: python, sqlite

I'm looking to store GUIDs in my SQLite database, using C# and python clients.

Creating a database, and inserting a row, storing the GUID as a string:

```
conn = sqlite3.connect(filename)

c = conn.cursor()

# Create the table. Yes, I know GUID isn't a real SQLite datatype.
c.execute('CREATE TABLE test (guid GUID PRIMARY KEY, name text)')

u = uuid.uuid4()
print u
t = (str(u), 'foo')
c.execute('INSERT INTO test VALUES (?,?)', t)

conn.commit()
conn.close()
```

Fetching:

```
# ...
c.execute('SELECT * FROM test WHERE guid = "c1332103-6031-4ff7-b610-f8f3b940fa66"')
print c.fetchone()
```

This all works perfectly. Using the default Python `__str__` representation of the UUID works well.

```
C:\Users\Jonathon>makedb.py test.db
c1332103-6031-4ff7-b610-f8f3b940fa66

C:\Users\Jonathon>opendb.py test.db
(u'c1332103-6031-4ff7-b610-f8f3b940fa66', u'foo')
```

---

My doubts arise from using [SQLite Expert](http://www.sqliteexpert.com/index.html). It appears that SQLite Expert is happy with my GUID datatype declaration:

[image]

But, if I edit a row:

[image]

it seems that it changes the datatype! My `SELECT` from before yields `None`, and if I `SELECT *`, I see that it is no longer a simple unicode string:

```
C:\Users\Jonathon>opendb.py test.db
(<read-write buffer ptr 0x02239520, size 16 at 0x02239500>, u'foo')
```

---

Looking at the data on disk, you can see that the GUID is stored in binary, after SQLite Expert touches it:

Before - the GUID is ASCII text:

[image]

After - the previous data is garbage, and a binary version of the GUID exists:

[image]

---

So what is the *"correct"* way to store GUIDs in SQLite, specifically using Python? Later, I will have C# code interacting with this as well, and want to make sure I'm going things the "right" way.

Comment: Don't make the `GUID`/`UUID` the primary key, use a separate internal id - especially if you are intending to make foreign key relationships, see http://www.mail-archive.com/sqlite-users%40sqlite.org/msg27377.html

Comment: SQLite (and hence SQLite Expert) are happy with the `GUID` type because SQLite doesn't enforce types (except on `INTEGER PRIMARY KEY` field).

Comment: Hmm, there appears to be a conflict of opinion:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3272013/guid-as-uniq-key-with-sqlite

Comment: Right, but obviously SQLite Expert is treating it specially. Should I be storing my GUIDs as binary blobs instead of strings? If that's the case, it seems that would make it trickier to SELECT on.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

One can essentially add support for GUID datatypes to sqlite3 in Python.  You can register conversion functions:

- [`register_converter()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.register_converter): convert SQLite types to Python types
- [`register_adapter()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.register_adapter): convert Python types to SQLite types

To use these, you need to pass an argument for the `detect_types` parameter of [`connect()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.connect).

Example:

```
import sqlite3
import uuid

sqlite3.register_converter('GUID', lambda b: uuid.UUID(bytes_le=b))
sqlite3.register_adapter(uuid.UUID, lambda u: buffer(u.bytes_le))

conn = sqlite3.connect('test.db', detect_types=sqlite3.PARSE_DECLTYPES)

c = conn.cursor()
c.execute('CREATE TABLE test (guid GUID PRIMARY KEY, name TEXT)')

data = (uuid.uuid4(), 'foo')
print 'Input Data:', data
c.execute('INSERT INTO test VALUES (?,?)', data)

c.execute('SELECT * FROM test')
print 'Result Data:', c.fetchone()
```

Output:

```
Input Data: (UUID('59cc2646-8666-4fb3-9f57-fe76e22603c0'), 'foo')
Result Data: (UUID('59cc2646-8666-4fb3-9f57-fe76e22603c0'), u'foo')
```

Results:

- I am passing [`uuid.UUID`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/uuid.html) objects directly to `execute()`. The adapter `lambda u: buffer(u.bytes)` tells sqlite3 how to convert those to a `buffer` (which translates to an `X'ABCD....'` blob in SQLite.
- `fectchone()` is returning `uuid.UUID` objects directly.  The converter `lambda u: buffer(u.bytes)` tells sqlite3 how to create those from a byte array when it encounters a declared type of `GUID`.
- These GUIDs are being stored as 16-byte binary blobs, in little-endian order.
- I can successfully open/edit the databases using SQLite Expert (in its default configuration).

Answer (score 5):

Your GUID is a string.  Declare it as a VARCHAR or CHAR and it will pick up the text affinity correctly.  As GUID is not a type the field has no type affinity, and thus will have the datatype of NONE.

This is described here:  http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html

There is also a brief discussion of someone trying to use a Guid within SQLite Expert on their support forum here:  http://sqliteexpert.com/forum/YaBB.pl?num=1368018774/0

Support talks about the mapping system and how to change a mapping, as well as the tool defaulting to the use of a Blob.

Comment: So is what I'm seeing just a strange behavior of SQLite Expert, due to my GUID datatype declaration?

Comment: Looks like it - I just downloaded and had a look. If you use the GUI to define fields it has "GUID" as one of the options.

Comment: Yes, basically, since GUID is an unknown type, SQLite can't figure out a type affinity for it.

Comment: But *someone* is parsing the ASCII GUID, and storing it as a 16-byte binary blob. Is it SQLite Expert or the SQLite library?

Comment: SQLite has no native concept of a GUID. It must be the SQLite Expert application that's mangling the GUID this way.

Comment: SQLite Expert implements its types through a mapping system internal to the tool.  Often this type of thing is referred to as a "domain" where you are able to create your own name for a datatype.  Their GUID types map to blob inside SQLite expert, but you can change the mapping in the tool.