# SQLite3 selects fail on UUIDs after registering converter

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite

I am having an issue when using SQLite and UUID solution as suggested by [@Jonathan Reinhart](https://stackoverflow.com/users/119527/jonathon-reinhart) [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18821265/proper-way-to-store-guid-in-sqlite/18842491) I am using Python3 and the error I get when doing selects in DB is:

```
sqlite3.register_converter('guid', lambda b: UUID(bytes_le=b))
File "/usr/lib/python3.6/uuid.py", line 146, in __init__
  raise ValueError('bytes_le is not a 16-char string')
ValueError: bytes_le is not a 16-char string
```

The values received are proper UUIDs.

I'm a bit puzzled by the error, since in the original answer it seems to work. Can someone provide some clarification? I am able to make inserts into the DB, only the selects fail.
I can do selects directly in the DB and I don't get any errors, but not with sqlite3 python cursor.

Thank you, much appreciated.

Comment: What does the data look like in the database?

Comment: `sqlite> select *, datetime(created, 'unixepoch') from operators;`

`da76af2c-efd1-11e7-88fd-240a64949101|1256|John Smith|1||1514907025|1514907025||2018-01-02 15:30:25

da78d81a-efd1-11e7-88fd-240a64949101|1340|Bob Marley|1||1514907025|1514907025||2018-01-02 15:30:25

da7a6a9a-efd1-11e7-88fd-240a64949101|1522|Jane Doe|0||1514907025|1514907025||2018-01-02 15:30:25

da7bfa7c-efd1-11e7-88fd-240a64949101|2784|Jack Bear|0||1514907025|1514907025||2018-01-02 15:30:25`

Comment: The answer you linked involves storing the UUIDs in the database in a compact binary form. It won't apply here where it's actually stored in the longer text form.

Comment: Thank you @glibdud!!! That fixed the problem. I was converting the data to store, before doing the inserts.